# Python: How to use a third-party library

Tags: python, libraries

I am feeling completely stupid. I am a Python beginner and would like to use third-party libraries, such as [dxfgrabber](http://pythonhosted.org/dxfgrabber/).

I have played with the following, which is given in the help section, but I don't know further:

```
import dxfgrabber

dxf = dxfgrabber.readfile("1.dxf")

print("DXF version: {}".format(dxf.dxfversion))

header_var_count = len(dxf.header) 

layer_count = len(dxf.layers) 

entity_count = len(dxf.entities) 

print layer_count

print entity_count

print dxf.layers
```

output so far is:

```
DXF version: AC1009

6

2

<dxfgrabber.layers.LayerTable object at 0x10f42b590>
```

my questions:

- So I know that there are 6 layers and 2 entities. How can I get further information like: layer name, which entities?
- How can I actually access the entities (for example I know that there are two lines)? How can I get the lines?
- I would like to write code so that the entities (such as lines) are displayed on a canvas.

It seems like this library should be ready to use, but maybe for people with more knowledge about Python than me.

Answer (score 1):

Try for example:

```
for layer in dxf.layers:
    print layer.name, layer.color
```

**Explanation**:

The output of your last print command indicates that `dxf.layers` is a `LayerTable` object. In the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/dxfgrabber/#Layer) you can see that a `LayerTable` object has a property:

```
LayerTable.__iter__()
Iterate over all layers, yields Layer objects.
```

This means that it can be iterated in a for loop or whatever construction that takes an iterable. In the case of entities you can do something like this:

```
all_layer_0_entities = [entity for entity in dwg.entities if entity.layer == '0']
```

Here applies the same principle, the object dwg.entities is being iterated yielding an entity in each iteration.

You are right that the documentation could use more examples. See [this post](http://www.kellbot.com/sdxf-python-library-for-dxf/) for some of that.

Answer (score 1):

From your last print you can see that you have a `LayerTable` object; the [documentation for `LayerTable`](http://pythonhosted.org/dxfgrabber/#layer-table) says there should be a `.layernames()` method, as well as a `.get(layername)` method to get at individual layers.

It also states that you can iterate over the object (there is a `.__iter__()` method), so you can use `for layer in dxf.layers:` to get at individual [`Layer` objects](http://pythonhosted.org/dxfgrabber/#Layer).

The same information is available for the [`EntitySection` object](http://pythonhosted.org/dxfgrabber/#EntitySection), it too has an `__iter__()` method to loop over the 2 entities defined. The documentation then list the [entity types](http://pythonhosted.org/dxfgrabber/#base-class-shape) that you could encounter, with further documentation on how to access their information.

Unfortunately, there is at least one bug in the library; the `LayerTable.__iter__()` method doesn't return the correct type of object. A quick glance at the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/mozman/dxfgrabber/src/f09dd32b8dada172b32525a953d0aa0beafc745f?at=default) shows that other `__iter__()` methods *do* return correct items.

You can use

```
for layername in dxf.layers.layernames():
    layer = dxf.layers.get(layername)
```

instead for now, or call the `__iter__()` method directly:

```
for layer in dxf.layers.__iter__():
    # ..
```

I've filed a [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/mozman/dxfgrabber/pull-request/1) to fix the issue.

Comment: to @elyase:  I tried `for layer in dxf.layers:
    print layer.name, layer.color` which gives me `...TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'list'`

Comment: @solarisman: Interesting, that sounds like a bug in the library. Use `for layer in dxf.layers.__iter__():` for now instead, but do report it to the project if you can.

Comment: @solarisman: having looked a little at the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/mozman/dxfgrabber/src/f09dd32b8dada172b32525a953d0aa0beafc745f/dxfgrabber/layers.py?at=default) I can see more, minor mistakes; the `.__iter__()` method is most certainly broken. Instead of `return self._layers.values()` is should use `return iter(self._layers.values())`.